# Populate @Html.DropDownList with a List<string> using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, html-select

I'm trying to populate a @Html.DropDownList with a List using MVC and Razor.
Bellow is my code for the controller. So I need to pick the list out of my ViewBag and fill the dropdownlist.

```
public ActionResult Register()
    {
        sparklingEntities context = new sparklingEntities();
        var query = (from discs in context.Disciplines
                     select discs).ToList();
        List<string> listOfDiscs = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            listOfDiscs.Add(item.Discipline);
        }
        ViewBag.ListOfDisciplines = listOfDiscs;
        return View();
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If this is in an Editor for your model property:

```
@Html.DropDownList("", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfDisciplines, Model))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Increase performance by Eliminating foreach loop!
public ActionResult Register()
{
    sparklingEntities context = new sparklingEntities();
    var query = (from discs in context.Disciplines
                 select discs.Discipline); // change this line as discs.Discipline
    ViewBag.ListOfDisciplines = listOfDiscs;
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

value is not getting saves in the database..please see where i am getting mistake...

```
    public ActionResult Role(Role_Master_Table t)
    {
        FTSdatabaseEntities dc = new FTSdatabaseEntities();
        {

            //ViewBag.Status_Description = new SelectList(dc.Status_Master_Table, "StatusId", "Status_Description", "Remarks");
            var query = (from Status_Description in dc.Status_Master_Table
                         select Status_Description).ToList();
            List<string> listOfDiscs = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                listOfDiscs.Add(t.Status);
                dc.Role_Master_Table.Add(t);
                dc.SaveChanges();

            }
            ViewBag.Status_Description = listOfDiscs;


            return View();
        }
```