# How to populate data on a dropdownlist from existing SQL DB ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I have a database name CostDB on a SQLserver. I need to create a page (ASP.Net MVC 4) with a simple dropdown list (i.e. **Company Name**) which will be directly bind to the **Company** column of **DESE** table from the **CostDB** database.

I am lost after looking at all tutorials and ASP.Net MVC4's own tutorials that what way to start? There are different ways of code first, model first etc. I already have the database. Do I need to create a Model first in this case? If so does it have to be exact name match from the DB table names? Or do I generate the model from the database?Which functions would I need to create if I need to show data in the **dropdownlist** on page load? Most importantly what is the order to create an MVC application for an existing DB. Among M,V,C, what to create first?

Completely new to ASP.Net MVC 4. Already did go through MVCMovies tutorial but with no luck. Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best answer is this: Whatever you are comfortable with and what works for you.  There are tons of different approaches to development, and variations of each of those approaches.  I tend to lean towards database first, as I don't have as much experience in code first.

Since you already have a database created, I think the easiest approach for your method would be to generate an EDMX off of your existing structure and go from there.  Once you have the EDMX built and all the appropriate files referenced, it should be easy.  Just populate a list from your EF model, toss it into the ViewBag, and then populate your control(s).

Here is a good link on how to do this.  [Populate @Html.DropDownList with a List using MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333270/populate-html-dropdownlist-with-a-liststring-using-mvc)

I would highly recommend PluralSight for learning any type of development, one of the best sites I have ever used.  Best of luck!

Comment: I have started with generating the EDMX. Thanks for giving giving a heads up.

Comment: Pluralsights tutorials are costly :(